# How to test a fuel pressure regulator

Tags: fuel-system

How can you test a fuel pressure regulator if the car has no fuel pressure

I removed the tank and fuel pump even though I heard it prime, I tested the ohms on the gas leveler and the ohms did rise as the float rised, I also checked the value by testing the continuity, it showed it to be a Closed loop when off and open loop when power was supplied, then the sensor had a freyed wire so that wire was fixed, the tank reinstalled and still no start, no pressure. Fuses and relays are good, the filter is built into the pump and I was able to blow through it

I took off one of the fuel line connectors under the drivers seat to see if the fuel pump was pumping fuel out to the engine, and there was nothing, I don't know if it took off the return line or the supply line though. What I'm lost on is the fuel pressure regulator.

Can it prevent flow back to the fuel tank and can it cause no pressure to the injectors. How is it diagnosed if there's no pressure and no start.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to test a regulator, I would supply it with fuel at relevant pressure and a suitable electrical supply, with pressure gauges to see what happens...

But, reading your post, I don't think that is what you need to find first...

You should make sure the pump is working, you say you have checked the fuses, but do you have the supply at the pump? If so, have you checked for a good earth as well. You need to make sure fuel is being delivered.